# Why is the length of an empty slice equal to 1 after strings.Split?

Tags: string, go

When splitting a string, using `strings.Split`, if the input string is empty, the resulting empty slice have a length of 1.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    emptySlice1 := []string{}
    debugSlice( emptySlice1 ) // prints "[], []string, len 0"
    someStringToSplit := ""
    emptySlice2 := strings.Split(someStringToSplit , " ")
    debugSlice( emptySlice2 ) // prints "[], []string, len 1"
}

func debugSlice( s []string ){
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T, len %v\n", s, s, len(s))
}
```

Playground can be found here : https://play.golang.org/p/kBYR048UtP_0

Why is that?
How can I check the actual number of items inside a slice (if not with `len` function)?

Answer (score 7):

Becuase it's not empty but a slice that contains one `string`, which is the empty `string`.

Print it like:

```
fmt.Printf("%q, %T, len %v\n", s, s, len(s))
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j6v7pZcEbD-)):

```
[], []string, len 0
[""], []string, len 1
```

Doc of [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

> ```
> func Split(s, sep string) []string
> ```
>
> If s does not contain sep and sep is not empty, Split returns a slice of length 1 whose only element is s.

This is exactly what happens. You pass the empty string to `strings.Split()` (which is `s`) which obviously doesn't contain the non-empty separator `" "`, so `strings.Split()` returns a slice of length 1 whose only element is `s` (the empty string).

In other words: You ask to split a string with a separator that is not found in the input, so the result (output) is the input itself.

Comment: @Eria From package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/): `%q    a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax`. This is so empty strings and control characters will become visible on your terminal.